# Decorating a function only when used in a module

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am sorry if the question title is vague, I could not think of a better one.

I have a bunch of functions inside a module which I wish behaved differently when called locally versus when called from other modules.

Here is a toy example
moduleA.py

```
def func(arg1):
     pass
     do something
```

moduleB.py

```
import moduleA
func(arg1)
```

In moduleB the call for `func()` needs to do

```
initSomething
func(arg1)
doSomethingElse
```

And when `func()` is called from moduleA, I still need the original behavior. 
While the problem screams at me for using decorators, I am not sure on writing a decorator for `func()` that will be triggered only when called from a module.

Comment: Can you explain the context why you want that to happen? I have a hard time imagining a useful application for that.

Comment: Why not just have a public vs. private interface? `def _foo(): do_local()` and `def foo(): _foo(); doSomethingElse()`

Comment: @cwallenpoole: that is a good suggestion, but what if I have to do this about 20 functions. For simplicity, the `initSomething` and `doSomethingElse` stays the same for all of them.

Comment: A decorator is still equivalent to `name = decorator(name)`. So you can import the function and replace the imported name like shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to like you want to give the function calls a certain context. That's what context managers are for. You could do sth like:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def func_context():
    # init_something
    yield
    # do_something_else

with func_context():
    func(arg1)
```